# How to make namesList array position the same (synchronized) across multiple clients? (java multithreaded socket)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Screenshot of program running (top is server, bottom right is first client, bottom left is second client):

[Screenshot of program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPoZV.png)

The problem with the screenshot above is that the message that appears on the bottom left window `User name: something has been added to position 0 in the namesList array` should instead be `User name: something has been added to position 1 in the namesList array` The reason the position needs to be 1 instead of 0 is because the first name should be stored in the first position, and the second name should be stored in the second position (to make the list of names actually store all of the names)

The issue is making the namesList array and position sync.

EDIT: it seems that `threads[i]` has global accessibility, is it possible that I should make an arraylist of file names with objects to somehow store the names of the connected clients instead of a regular string array to store them?

What changes can I make to the following code that would make the array sync and accessible to all clients?

ChatThreads.java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
class ClientThreads extends Thread
{
  public String name1 = "";
  private String clientName = null;
  private DataInputStream is = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  private final ClientThreads[] threads;
  private int maxClientsCount;
  public static String[] namesList = new String[4];
  public int iteration = 0;
  public static String[] responses = new String[50];
  public int responseCount = 0;

  public ClientThreads(Socket clientSocket, ClientThreads[] threads, String name)
  {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
    this.name1 = name;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public void run() 
  {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    ClientThreads[] threads = this.threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < namesList.length; i++)
     {
         namesList[i] = "";
     }
     for(int j = 0; j < responses.length; j++)
     {
         responses[j] = "";
     }
    try 
    {
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      String name;
      String firstName;
      while (true) 
      {
        os.println("What is your name?");
        name = is.readLine().trim();
          break;
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this)
          {
            clientName = "@" + name;
            break;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null)
          {
            threads[i].os.println(name + " has connected.");
            os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");
          }
        }
      }
      while (true)
      {
        String line = is.readLine();
        if (line.startsWith("/quit")) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");
        }

        if(line.equals("x") || line.equals("X"))
        {
            os.println("x");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(line.equals("m") || line.equals("M"))
        {
          os.println("Enter your message: ");
        }
        if(line.equals("f") || line.equals("F"))
        {
          os.println("Who owns the file?");
          boolean keep = true;
          while (keep == true)
          {
            String fileOwner = is.readLine();

            if(fileOwner !=null && !fileOwner.isEmpty())
            {
                responses[responseCount] = fileOwner + "`owns a file";
                responseCount++;
                os.println(fileOwner);
                namesList[iteration] = fileOwner;
                System.out.println("User named: " + fileOwner + " has been added to position " + iteration + " in the namesList array.");
                iteration++;
                keep = false;
                os.println("Which file do you want?");
                boolean keep2 = true;
                while(keep2==true)
                {
                  String filename = is.readLine();
                  if(filename !=null && !filename.isEmpty())
                  {
                     // os.println(filename);
                      keep2 = false;
                      os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");
                  }
                }
            }
          }
        }
        else 
        {
          synchronized (this)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) 
            {
              if (!line.equals("x") && !line.equals("X") && !line.equals("f") && !line.equals("F") && !line.equals("m") && !line.equals("M") && threads[i] != null && threads[i].clientName != null && !threads[i].clientName.equals("m") && !threads[i].clientName.equals("M")) 
              {
                threads[i].os.println(name + ": " + line + "\n");
                this.os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this && threads[i].clientName != null)
          {
            threads[i].os.println(name + "has disconnected.");
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] == this) 
          {
            threads[i] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      is.close();
      os.close();
      clientSocket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    }
  }
}
```

ChatClient.java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatClient implements Runnable 
{

  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  private static DataInputStream is = null;
  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;
  public static String[] namesList = new String[4];
  public int iteration = 0;
  public static String[] responses = new String[50];
  public int responseCount = 0;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < namesList.length; i++)
     {
         namesList[i] = "";
     }
     for(int j = 0; j < responses.length; j++)
     {
         responses[j] = "";
     }
    int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[3]);
    String host = "localhost";
    int filePort = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
    try 
    {
      clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
      inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
      System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
          + host);
    }
    if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null)
    {
      try 
      {

        new Thread(new ChatClient()).start();
        while (!closed)
        {
          os.println(inputLine.readLine() );
        }

        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
    }
  }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run()
{


    String responseLine = "";
    try 
    {
      while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null)
      {
          if(responseLine.equals("x") || responseLine.equals("X"))
          {
              System.exit(0);
          }
          if(responseLine.equals("Who owns the file?") && !responseLine.isEmpty() && responseLine != null)
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);
              responses[responseCount] = "234782375920192831";

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("Which file do you want?"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("What is your name?"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("m") || responseLine.equals("M"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println("Enter your message: ");
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n"))
          {

              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);  
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine != null && !responseLine.isEmpty() && !responseLine.equals("What is your name?") && !responseLine.equals("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n") && !responseLine.equals("Who owns the file?") && !responseLine.equals("Which file do you want?"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              if(responses[responseCount-1].equals("234782375920192831"))
              {
                  namesList[iteration] = responseLine;
                  System.out.println("User named: " + responseLine + " has been added to position " + iteration + " in the namesList array." );
                  iteration++;
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println(responseLine);  
                  responses[responseCount] = responseLine;
              }
          }
      }
      closed = true;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

ChatServer.java code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ChatServer
{

  public static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  public static Socket clientSocket = null;
  public static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  public static final ClientThreads[] threads = new ClientThreads[maxClientsCount];

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

      if(args.length <3)
      {
          int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
          System.out.println("waiting for connections on port " + portNumber + " ...\n ");
      }
    try 
    {
      int portNumber1 = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber1);
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    while (true) 
    {
      try
      {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
            if (threads[i] == null)
            {
                String name = "";
                (threads[i] = new ClientThreads(clientSocket, threads, name)).start();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == maxClientsCount)
        {
          PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
          os.close();
          clientSocket.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ServerThread.java code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class ServerThread
{

  private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  private static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  private static final ClientThreads[] threads = new ClientThreads[maxClientsCount];

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

     int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
     if(args.length <3)
     {
         System.out.println("waiting for conennections on port" + portNumber + " ...\n ");
     }
    try 
    {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    while (true) 
    {
      try
      {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) 
        {
          if (threads[i] == null) 
          {
            String name = "";
            (threads[i] = new ClientThreads(clientSocket, threads, name)).start();
            break;
          }
        }
        if (i == maxClientsCount) 
        {
          PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
          os.close();
          clientSocket.close();
        }
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: How would I make the namesList array the same across multiple clients with the position?

Comment: There is no easy way given by the JVM. You have to come up with a protocol and the code implementing it so that the list gets synchonized between your clients.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle is it possible to put an if statement inside `synchronized(this){}` without using threads[i] or is threads[i] necessary to print it out to all the clients?

Comment: for what purpose? Don't you think you could get rid of this `if/else` cascase by holding the clients in a `List` rather then an array?

Comment: why do you think a `List` would be globally synchronized when an array cannot be or do you think they both could be?

Comment: *"why do you think a List would be globally synchronized"* did I imply that in any way?